# What does this error in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using the Zymic Database Uploader v1.1 to upload my XAMPP/MySQL database to zymic database.
I followed the instruction carefully until I got this error.

```
Error at the line 27: ) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci MAX_ROWS=15000; 

Query: CREATE TABLE `bmf_chatting` (
`usr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`usr_name` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`chatto` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci MAX_ROWS=15000;


MySQL: Table 'bmf_chatting' already exists
```

This happened while I was Processing/Importing the database into Zymic but it stopped on error. I have no database yet in my zymic and I have no duplicate table 'bmf_chatting'.

I thought it will be a simple export/import. :(

Comment: Two create statements in your database import?

Comment: Are you on the right database?

Comment: `Table 'bmf_chatting' already exists` - what do you don't understand? ;-) Maybe you just want to import data but already have the structure? ;-)

Comment: @thedom i want to import the structure with no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dump file, if this table didn't get exported twice for whatever reason.

Also make sure, to drop all tables (and maybe the entire database) before you retry with you import. Whatever tables are created above this one, have already been created.

Comment: so i have to remove the dump file?

Comment: No. Remove any database object that have been created before that error occured. When an import like this stops due to error, anything that was already imported is not deleted automatically. You must do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you had a table called bmf_chatting in MySQL before and it was improperly deleted (the files were probably deleted without dropping the database).

Try running a drop database query before your create query.